# Asbestos in my furnace closet - should I get rid of it?

Tags: furnace, safety, asbestos, health-and-safety, closet

I have a home built in 1958 with a closet inside the house that contains the furnace. When the house was constructed this closet was lined with asbestos as a safety measure. How dangerous is it for my family members if this closet door remains closed? Should I make a priority of removing the asbestos and/or migrating the furnace out of the house altogether?

Comment: What condition is the insulation in? Is the furnace forced hot air or a water boiler?

Comment: Hard smooth asbestos sheets (Transite® board) or fluffy stuff? the best thing to do with Transite is leave it alone - it's not prone to making lose fibers if you leave it be.

Comment: @HenryJackson I believe it is forced air.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's the fluffy stuff, sadly.

Comment: The combination of fluffy insulation and forced hot air would make me really nervous — in theory the air should just be recirculating, but unless the ductwork is perfectly sealed I bet it's pulling in a small amount of air from the closet and blowing it around the house. However I don't really know anything about asbestos, so I don't know if this is actually a problem.